# Angular Forms: Front-end is not displaying the image when I update the product

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am doing a tutorial, I have reached the part where I can create a product seamlessly, but when I go to update the same product, the image is not updated, even if I don't change it, it appears blank.

Here is the component TS file:

```
 private _checkEditMode() {
      this.router.params.subscribe((params) => {
        if (params['id']) {
          this.editMode = true;
          this.currentProductId = params['id'];
          this.productsService
            .getProduct(params['id'])
            .subscribe((product) => {
             ...       
             ...      
              this.imageDisplay = product.image ; // I FEEL LIKE THERE IS SOMETHING WRONG WITH THIS LINE, 
            ...
            ...  
            });
        }
      });
    }
```

Here is the service ts code:

```
export class ProductsService {
  
  apiURLProducts = environment.apiUrl + 'products';

 updateProduct(productData: FormData, productid: string): Observable<Product> {
    return this.http.put<Product>(`${this.apiURLProducts}/${productid}`, productData);
  }
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
 <tr>
  ...
  ...
   <td style="width: 15%;"><img [src]="product.image"  style="width: 100%" alt="" /></td>
  ...
  ...
 </tr>
```

Someone suggested to me to define 'product.image', if that is the case, how do I go about it? Thanks.

Comment: how this method is called? private _checkEditMode() { - Also It will be good to have stackblitz

Comment: Would this work? https://angular-xcwndi.stackblitz.io

The concerned files are app > pages > product 
Thanks

Comment: Your URL shows errors https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcwndi?file=README.mdhttps://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcwndi?file=README.md - Import error, can't find files:
/src/index.html
/src/main.ts

Comment: Thanks. But I can see both the files there. I can't understand what might be the problem.

Comment: Now it is just 2 files inside - package.json & README

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML does not know `product` as it's a private argument of the subscribe method.

But from my understanding, as you put `product.image` into `this.imageDisplay`
You should bind `src` to `imageDisplay`

`<img [src]="imageDisplay" style="width: 100%" alt="" />`

Assuming the service is working properly and imageDisplay is a public member of the component

Comment: Thank you An0d. I think you are right but the problem is that this HTML belongs to a 'Product List Page' and the Edit Form is on the 'Product Form Page', hence imageDisplay doesn't exist on Product List Page. What should I do now?

Comment: Without the full picture of the project (Stackblitz ?), can't help further sorry

Comment: I will try to set it up. Thanks,

Comment: would this work? https://angular-xcwndi.stackblitz.io Thanks! 

The concerned files are app > pages > product